# python cProfile/snakeviz can't handle multiple functions calling same function

Tags: python, cprofile

I'm having issues interpreting `cProfile` data. To show you my problem I created this simple script.

The function D calls B and C, which both call A.
Function A clearly takes up 1 sec (+overhead).
If we look at the snakeviz results then you can see that the reporting is a bit weird. I understand that in total 2 sec has been spent by function A, but inside function C, function A has spent only 1 sec, and that's what I am interested in. Does anybody know if there is a setting (or a different viewer) where I do not have this issue?

```
import time
import cProfile

def A():
    time.sleep(1)

def B():
    A()

def C():
    A()

def D():
    B()
    C()

cProfile.run('D()','profileResults.prf')
```

[snakeviz results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hciUf.png)

Comment: As you are profiling function `D()`, where function `A()` is called indirectly 2 times, that's why it is showing 2 seconds.  

Function `C()` is called only once from `D()`.
From function `C()`, function `A()` is also called only once. Therefore function `C()` time should be 1 second.  If you profile function `C()` alone, you will get 1 second everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not showing wrong information indeed, and in this case one could just profile function C or D separately. However in more complex projects this is not possible. Once you're multiple levels deep in your code, it becomes impossible to determine how much time was spent in a function. I have found something which does it slightly better: https://ymichael.com/2014/03/08/profiling-python-with-cprofile.html

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the Python profile does not store the entire call tree. (This would be too expensive.) I've documented the problem [here](https://github.com/nschloe/tuna#but-tuna-doesnt-show-the-whole-call-tree) and as a [snakeviz issue](https://github.com/jiffyclub/snakeviz/issues/112).

I recently created [tuna](https://github.com/nschloe/tuna) for visualizing Python profiles to work around some of these problems. `tuna` cannot show the entire call tree, but at least it doesn't show wrong info either.

Install with

```py
pip3 install tuna
```

Create a runtime profile

```
python -m cProfile -o program.prof yourfile.py
```

and just run tuna on the file

```
tuna program.prof
```

[image]